# How To Search More Carefully In Files With Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, python-3.6

I get a file name from a user & upload the file for him/her, My problem is that due to my code, User should enter the file name to upload it, But I want to search more carefully & upload all files that their name is like the name user entered, How I can write it instead of this code?

Example : When user type Biology, The programm should upload files that are like Campbell Biology, My Biology Or ...

I need something LIKE Statement in SQL ...

```
try:
    requested_file = open(str(args[0]) + '.pdf', 'rb')
```

Comment: I guess with is scheme the user might end up uploading lots of private files they didn't want to upload.

Comment: @ForceBru The program search for files & send for them not users ...

Comment: You can either use regex or glob with wildcards.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Can you please show me an example in answer?

Comment: Maybe you should read the docs for the standard `glob` module.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to get all files which contain the particular search string the user enters. There are two options, the second one being more thorough than the first.

**Option 1**
You can use the `glob.glob` function, passing wildcards:

```
import glob

search = ... # your term here
for files in glob.glob('*%s*.pdf' % search):
    ... # do something with file
```

---

**Option 2**
`re.search` + `os.listdir`. You can traverse your present directory and filter with regex.

```
import os
import re

pattern = re.compile('.*%s.*\.pdf' %search, re.I)
for files in filter(pattern.search, os.listdir('.')):
    ... # do something with files
```

The second option offers you a little more flexibility. `glob` is limited by the wildcard syntax.

Comment: @AliBahaari You can also upvote answers that were helpful to you. Cheers.